# How to put a nav-bar in header image such that the nav-bar is transparent?

Tags: image, header, navigation

I have to place navigation bar in the header image, such that it becomes transparent and i'm using the theme Diario. I know how to make nav-bar transparent but donot know how to position it on the header image.
Please help.
Thanking a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you could always use `position: absolute` so that you can move it without moving anything else